# Android Studio: How to read classes from a jar file from a library?

Tags: android, android-studio, jar

I have two projects that use the same library. This library uses a `jar` file as a dependency, however only the library is able to read the classes from the `jar` file. The two projects don't have access to the classes from the `jar` file.

I tried adding the jar file to the two projects separately, but I get a build error, probably because now it's included in the project level and library level resulting in conflicts.

The `jar` file is `YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar`

```
                /------------------- Project1 (can't read classes from jar)
Library(w/ jar)
                \------------------- Project2 (can't read classes from jar)
```

Any ideas on how to approach? Thanks!

Comment: "The two projects don't have access to the classes from the jar file."- why not? If it's included as a dependency, it must.

Comment: What do your gradle files looks like? Are you on Android studio 3.0 with the latest gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using gradle 4.1, make sure to use the `api` keyword when importing the .jar into your library.  Then remove it from your other projects.

for example: `api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

[from the documentation:](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations)

> When a module includes an api dependency, it's letting Gradle know that the module wants to transitively export that dependency to other modules, so that it's available to them at both runtime and compile time. This configuration behaves just like compile (which is now deprecated), and you should typically use this only in library modules. That's because, if an api dependency changes its external API, Gradle recompiles all modules that have access to that dependency at compile time. So, having a large number of api dependencies can significantly increase build times. Unless you want to expose a dependency's API to a separate test module, app modules should instead use implementation dependencies.

Comment: Happy to help!  Migrating to gradle 4.1 isn't always straightforward.